# Vue - set default value to input text

Tags: vue.js, input

I'm loading a Vue component which should render a basic form. I'm trying to set the input to have a default value, but for some reason nothing shows. Here is what i tried:

```
<template>
    ...
    <input type="text" value="0.02" class="form-control" v-model="amount">
    ...
</template>
```

Why does nothing show into the input field? Is it because Vue doesn't support it or i need to use something else? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default value is set in `data` as follows:

```js
new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data() { return { amount: "0.02" } }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="amount">
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

The reason why you don't have a default value, is that this value is overwritten by the

```
v-model = "amount"
```

In order to set a default value, it would be better to set the value of `amount` in the returned vue data object.
You will have something like :

```
data:  () => {
return {
  amount: 0.02 // Your default value
 }
}
```

…

Comment: Indeed. I needed to set it from inside return {}. Thanks a lot